# Putting an image in the center of a black rectangle

Tags: python, image-processing

I would like to create a black rectangle with the bigger value of img.shape and then putting the image into the center of this black rectangle.

I coded this:

```
from skimage.io import imread
import numpy as np
#load the file_name
file_name = "/path/to/image/img.png"
#read in the image
img = imread(file_name)
#shape of image
img.shape
#create a black rectangle with length of sizes equal to the max of image.shape[0] or image.shape[1]
longSide = max(image.shape[0], image.shape[1])
#create a black square 
rectangle = np.zeros((longSide, longSide), dtype="bool")
```

I now would like to paste the image in the center of this black rectangle (the black rectangle in the background). In the end it should look like this:

[image: img]

Comment: Try putting back the `import` statements so we know what library you are using. Try removing the asterisk from your filename so your code actually runs. Try replacing the `if` statement with something like `longSide = max(image.shape[0], image.shape[1])`

Comment: Keep going... you can do it.

Comment: Okay, so what exactly is the question? What part do you think you can't do?

Comment: I don't know how to paste the image exactly in the middle of the rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the PIL (Pillow) image library:

```
from skimage.io import imread
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFilter

#load the file_name
file_name = "/path/to/image/img.png"
#read in the image
img = imread(file_name)
#shape of image
img.shape
#create a black rectangle with length of sizes equal to the max of image.shape[0] or image.shape[1]
longSide = max(image.shape[0], image.shape[1])
#create a black square 
rectangle = np.zeros((longSide, longSide), dtype="bool")

final_im = rectangle.copy()
final_im.paste(img, (100, 50))
# the final command is pasting the previous image on the rectangle, and positioning it using `(x coordinate in upper left, y coordinate in upper left)`.
```

More info: https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-pillow-paste/

Comment: `---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-1e06b51ee9d9> in <module>()
      1 final_im = rectangle.copy()
----> 2 final_im.paste(img, (100, 50))

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'paste'`I get this error.